# Format String - Java

Tags: java, string

How can the following line be formatted as a valid string in Java?

```
'//*[@id="pageBodyRight"]/div[4]/a/img'
```

Sorry, I'm new to Java. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want `'//*[@id=\"pageBodyRight\"]/div[4]/a/img'`?

Comment: Yes. I keep getting the errors "unclosed character literal" and "unclosed comment".

Comment: @user1880633 See also the "Escape Sequences" table down at the bottom of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

Answer (score 2):

Um..

```
String str = "'//*[@id=\"pageBodyRight\"]/div[4]/a/img'";
```

?

If you have double quotes in your string, you need to escape them with a backslash.

Answer (score 1):

escape the double quotes with a backslash like `\"`

```
    String sd ="'//*[@id=\"pageBodyRight\"]/div[4]/a/img'";
```

Comment: lol thanks for the edit >< you get a +1 :p

Answer (score 0):

```
    System.out.println("'//*[@id=\"pageBodyRight\"]/div[4]/a/img'");
```